# Gas .align instruction doesn't work correctly

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm using gas and trying to align a .lcomm buffer on 16 bytes.

Code :

```
.align 16

.lcomm Buffer, size
```

But when checking the address of Buffer using leal instruction. it seems that it is NOT aligned. I think that the .align directive doesn't work correctly.

Do you have any idea please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it works correctly, but you use it wrong.
The [manual says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Lcomm.html):

> Some targets permit a third argument to be used with .lcomm. This
>   argument specifies the desired alignment of the symbol in the bss
>   section.

So the correct code is `.lcomm Buffer, size, 16`.
Note that `.align` does not affect `.lcomm` especially if you are not in the `.bss` section. If you want to allocate stuff by hand, switch to `.bss`, then use the `.align` and then allocate using `.space` not `.lcomm`.

Also, the [manual gives a workaround suggestion](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Local.html) as:

> For targets where the .lcomm directive (see Lcomm) does not accept an
>   alignment argument, which is the case for most ELF targets, the .local
>   directive can be used in combination with .comm (see Comm) to define
>   aligned local common data.

Indeed, for x86 ELF the alignment argument is not supported, so implementing this workaround would look like:

```
.local Buffer
.comm Buffer, size, 16
```

(Thanks to [@wumpus-q-wumbley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404501/wumpus-q-wumbley) for pointing this out.)

Comment: There's also a suggestion under [`.local`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Local.html) to use `.local` together with `.comm` on targets that don't support the third argument.